# value was changed by using "<script>" but it is not shown on the page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
   var idn_text = "123"
   document.getElementById("idn_id").value = idn_text
</script>
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Results" name="idn" id="idn_id"></p>
```

the webpage does not display this value, it only displays it as an empty form. How to fix it?

Comment: Duplicate: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Also always check the console for errors. `document.getElementById("idn_id")` returns `null` so accessing .value of that causes an error which points to the problem.

Comment: @ChrisG, I am asking this question because I see that it is not a Null, I already checked it. It just does not display the value in the form for some reason

Comment: It is null, see for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/pLk02usw/

Answer (score -1):

Your input field has not rendered and the  script is looking  for an element with it's id. A simple solution is to move your script to end of the  html file. like this:

```
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Results" name="idn" id="idn_id"></p> 
<script>
   var idn_text = "123"
   document.getElementById("idn_id").value = idn_text
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to question that are already marked as dupes

Answer (score -1):

Switch the order of your elements and call the script afterwards.

```html
<p><input type="text" placeholder="Results" name="idn" id="idn_id"></p> 
<script>
   var idn_text = "123"
   document.getElementById("idn_id").value = idn_text
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to question that are already marked as dupes